# Can Storm topologies contain cycles?

Tags: graph, apache-storm, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have been reading papers about Apache Storm recently. From what I understood it is based on Directed Acyclic Graph of operations and streams of data.

However, in [Storm@Twitter](https://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs227/archives/2015/papers/ss-storm.pdf) it says:

> Note that a Storm topology can have cycles.

How does it apply to the definition of DAG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storm doesn't prevent you from making cycles in your topology. Example:

```
builder.setSpout("word", new TestWordSpout(), 10);
builder.setBolt("exclaim1", new ExclamationBolt(), 3)
    .shuffleGrouping("word")
    .shuffleGrouping("exclaim2");
builder.setBolt("exclaim2", new ExclamationBolt(), 2).shuffleGrouping("exclaim1");
```

See also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/storm-user/EjN1hU58Q_8. Cycles don't seem like a good idea, and I'd be surprised if they're commonly used.

Comment: I never said that it does, I said that paper mentions that it is possible and to me it seems to be something not allowed in directed acyclic graphs. That's what I am trying to understand.

Comment: You're right, a DAG can't have cycles. As a consequence some topology graphs are not DAGs. Topology graphs are commonly DAGs though, and the ability to create cyclic graphs seems to me to be a "happens to work". The area where Storm requires a DAG is with regard to tuple tracking. Take a look at http://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html.